fo2.exe app fail to use sfall ddraw.dll, or fallout2-ce.apk fail to start, how to fix?
fo2.exe Android app fail to use sfall ddraw.dll, or fallout2-ce.apk fail to start, how to fix?
Android 6.0.1, Samsung Galaxy J7, 32-bit phone.
Using GOG Fallout 2.
Using the latest After War: Nevada overhaul mod.
Tried also latest sfall ddraw.dll sfall.dat update.
fo2.exe Android app says "sfall is not enabled, enable it on app settings". But to enable it just requires ddraw.dll, sfall.dat, cfg and ini files to be present and they are all there...
Fallout2-ce.apk insists on "failed to initialize input" even after setting the background mouse and keyboard to 1 in ddraw.ini
What's the trick to make them work? Did tou make sfall work?
Should I use older or specific versions of Fallout 2, Nevada mod, sfall?
On Linux Wine, in ddraw.ini, I can set main menu offset x to 100 and it will work, after forcing native use of ddraw.dll, so ddraw.dll is being detected and loaded, but for some weird reason, despite the language being set to English in nevada.cfg, everything is in Russian (Nevada default language ignoring the nevada.cfg set to English) :/
fallout2-ce will load in English in Linux, but I want to play in Android! And fallout2-ce.apk won't start!
Any help?

Updated:
With the below workaround, sfall will work on linux wine with: wine Nevada but only with latest sfall version and vulkan d3d. That latest sfall will crash in fo2.exe app.
The sfall that comes with nevada will start to load in fo2.exe app and complain about fallout2.exe crc. Adding  the crc in ddraw.ini will avoid that error, but in j7 will still freeze, but may work for you, feel free to answer if you find a way to make it work, just copy whatever parts you need from here.
#### PATCH ddraw.dll to dtdrw.dll text ####

# prepare dtdrw.dll, it is still a wrapper to ddraw.dll, so it will not be modified below with sed
cp ddraw.dll dtdrw.dll

# patch all binaries that look for ddraw.dll to find dtdrw.dll instead
# the overwrite text must have the same size to not break the binary
# (obs.: fallout2.exe fallout2HR.exe NevadaHD.exe will never be used/run)
sed -i.`date +'%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S_%N'`.bkp -e 's@ddraw[.]dll@dtdrw.dll@g' -e 's@DDRAW[.]DLL@DTDRW.DLL@g' -e 's@DDRAW[.]dll@DTDRW.dll@g' Nevada.exe f2_res.dll F12SE/F12se.exe fallout2.exe fallout2HR.exe NevadaHD.exe 

# confirm
clear;egrep "(ddraw|dtdrw).dll" * -iRnIao --include="*.dll" --include="*.exe" 

# WINEDLLOVERRIDE wont be necessary now as dtdrw.dll overrides nothing: WINEDLLOVERRIDE="ddraw.dll=n" wine Nevada



#### PATCH ddraw.dll to dtdrw.dll CRC ####

# sfall (dtdrw.dll) will complaint of Nevada.exe wrong CRC ex.: 0xF746C240, that should be ex.: 0xE1680293. 930268E1 hexa order inverted here to easy find on hex editor like `bless dtdrw.dll`

# OR JUST appendd ,0xF746C240 to ddraw.ini ExtraCRC config ex.: ExtraCRC=0xC459EBDB,0xF9CE894F,0xA4BD8FFF,0xE60C7318,0xF746C240

# copy the CRC hexa 0xF746C240 that was read from Nevada.exe, invert each pair and paste in dtdrw.dll
# so paste (overwrite mode to not increase the size of the binary file) modified Nevada.exe CRC 40C246F7 over requested inside dtdrw.dll 930268E1 (there are two places to replace)
40C246F7 # (Nevada.exe) the hexa order is inverted here to easy paste on hex editor like `bless dtdrw.dll`, place the cursor on the begin of the hexa before pasting
#WARING: (do not try to run NevadaHD, sfall has HD and this patch will fail) 173884E8 # (NevadaHD.exe) the hexa order is inverted here to easy paste on hex editor like `bless dtdrw.dll`, place the cursor on the begin of the hexa before pasting
#WARING: (do not try to run fallout2HR, sfall has HR. not tested patching this)



#### in android, fo2.exe app tries to run fallout2.exe and not Nevada.exe at it's Nevada installation, why? ####
Before letting it copy the folder, rename fallout2.exe to fallout2.exe.bkp
duplicate Nevada.exe to fallout2.exe
This will stop the sfall CRC check error.
Obs.: after that it still did not work on J7 :(, but may work for you!



### TESTS ###
# running
fallout-ce # runs Nevada mod, runs very fast, shows the main menu offset but fails to allow pipboy from start, why?
wine Nevada # runs very slowly, will show the main menu offset and will let use pipboy from start, so the ddraw.ini configs works better

fallou2-ce.apk may require a pc mouse and keyboard plugged in the mini usb using a usb hub to work, or it has touch screen support? I think we need a usb otg and hub to test it then?
Til now the only thing that works here is vanilla fallout2, no mods no sfall, on fo2.exe app.

ddraw.dll could be renamed to sfall.dll and grant also that in all binary patches and update crc checks too
